# RadioButtonFor binding to Model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind a group of radio buttons to a value from my Model.  Normally this would be easy to do , but I am trying to change it a little bit so it works like this.  `IsEventsRegistration` is an Int and the possible choices are 0 - 5.  I want 3 radio buttons to be displayed at first to the user :

If `IsEventsRegistration` is 0 - select first radio button

If `IsEventsRegistration` is 1 - select second radio button

If `IsEventsRegistration` is > 1 - select the third radio button

and then another group of 4 radio buttons that was hidden with jquery will show up.  I can handle the hiding and showing of the radio groups with jQuery just fine.  My problem is - is there a way to bind these radio buttons to the value of `IsEventsRegistration` Making it so if the value is >1 , then my radio for `2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5` will be checked and also the correct Radio will be checked?

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 0) <a>...</a><br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 1) <a>...</a><br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration, 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5) <a>...</a><br />

<div class="hideRadios">
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 2) <a>...</a><br />
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 3) <a>...</a><br />
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 4) <a>...</a><br />
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 5) <a>...</a><br />
</div>
```

This is VB.Net , but a c# answer is just as good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are able to use javascript, here is what I would maybe recommend. Have the radio for the 2+ values not be part of the group of radios bound to `IsEventsRegistration.` When that is "clicked" show the extra values giving the user the ability to select one of them, or even default the radio selection to the first in the list. Don't forget to "uncheck" the 0 or 1 radio if it was checked before hand. If 0 or 1 is "clicked" collapse that more options group.

With the "show more" radio not part of the Model group, you shouldn't have to do anything special in your controller to parse the value out of it.

For the initial drawing, just have a `$(function () {...})` check to see if any of the "show more" radios are selected, and tick the outside radio button to trigger the .show functionality.

Roughly

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 0) <a>...</a><br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 1) <a>...</a><br />
<input id="more" type="radio" name="show-others">

<div class="hideRadios">
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 2) <a>...</a><br />
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 3) <a>...</a><br />
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 4) <a>...</a><br />
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventsRegistration , 5) <a>...</a><br />
</div>

$(document).on('click', '#more', function () {
  $(this).siblings('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
  $('.hideRadios').show();
});

$(function () {
  if ($('.hideRadios input:checked').val() > 1)
    $('#more').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: oh, one thing - Does the model fill in the values before jquery's $(document).ready()  ?

Comment: Yes, I think that the proper radio should be checked based on the model that your controller gives to your view. Essentially, whatever `x.IsEventsRegistration` equals will be the initial "checked" radio.

Answer (score 0):

I can not think how to do what you want...don't know if it is even possible... but I could suggest you some workaround.

Just create 2 properties in your model (ViewModel): one called `IsEventsRegistration` and a second called `IsEventsRegistrationAdvaced`.

Then, use the second property for the hidden radios.

With jQuery, unhide the second group of radiobuttons and select the first one.

This way, once posted back to server... you will have 2 values, and in case you need to save to a single field in database, you can add the logic in the controller action to check what to save.

If you then need to edit this, you will need some JS to set the current state of your radiobuttons, and then the JS logic will be the same as in the create view.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible, radio buttons are there for a single choice options.

I would divide radio buttons to two groups binded to the different model properties and process data in the controller.

Model:

```
class MyModel {
  ...
  public int IsEventRegistrationMain { get; set; }
  public int IsEventRegistrationDetail { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

View:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsEventRegistrationMain , 0) <a>...</a><br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsEventRegistrationMain , 1) <a>...</a><br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsEventRegistrationMain , 2) <a>...</a><br />

<div class="hideRadios">
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(x) x.IsEventRegistrationDetail , 2) <a>...</a><br />
  ...
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Process(MyModel model) {
  ...
  var IsEventRegistration = model.IsEventRegistrationMain == 2 ? model.IsEventRegistrationDetail : model.IsEventRegistrationMain;
  ...    
}
```